# Export Weka Models for Use in C or C++

Tags: java, c++, machine-learning, weka, classification

I have had a great deal of success using Weka for data exploration and deciding what classification algorithm is best for my problem. Now that I have a trained model that works, I would like to integrate it into the rest of my C++ program. Unfortunately, this seems like a difficult task: only Weka has native support for exporting classifiers as Java object files. Has anyone found a way to export Weka-trained model parameters in a useful format?

I would be particularly interested if there is a utility that generates C/C++ code from a J48 decision tree.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? In our work we had the same requirements and wound up implementing an exporter that writes the tree to JSON, and then C++ would read the JSON to instantiate the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that J48 is Java implementation of Quinlan C4.5 algorithm with C code freely available at http://www.rulequest.com/Personal/ Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Useful link, but not exactly what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to train a model in Weka (since it has good visualization tools), export the model parameters, and load them into a C or C++ implementation for production.

Comment: Have been working with Weka for 5-8 yeas, never heard of result exporting tools, but seen a lot of complaines about this Weka shortcoming. You might want to look RapidMiner - I am sure it has J48/C4.5 implemented and very rich result exporting functionality

Answer (score 1):

J48 implements the Sourcable interface, meaning it can output a built model as Java source code (you can probably achieve this from the classifier panel of the explorer gui). It might then be possible to automatically translate this into C/C++.